# Cycles: No transparency in 3D View in material viewport shading mode

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

I have a scene with two textured planes that cover each other. The textures are in png file format with alpha channel. The material nodes configuration is presented below:

[image: Cycles shader configuration]

I sure the material settings are correct:

[image: Material settings]

Unfortunately the transparency is not working in 3D View in Material viewport shading mode:

[image: Transparency in material viewport shading mode]

Meanwhile everything works in Rendered viewport shading mode:

[image: Transparency in Render]

What could be the problem?

Comment: The 3D view can sometimes do some screwy things, but I wouldn't worry about it. The final product is rendered, and no one will see the viewport but you.

Comment: This works for fine for me.. Could you upload your .blend?

Comment: I think the OpenGL view modes are not taking into account which objects are in front or behind one another(z-buffer). This makes transparency sensitive to the order with which objects are drawn.  Maybe it's something else.

Comment: It also depends on the specs of your computer. Some features of OpenGL are not supported with different cards.